# Where does discrete probabilities in Forward-Backward algorithm for Hidden Markov Models come from?

Tags: log-likelihood, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to derive a Forward-Backward algorithm used in Hidden Markov Models to compute the likelihood $P(x | \theta)$ that sample $x = (x_1, ... x_n)$ comes from HMM defined by set of parameters $\theta$ which includes:

- $k \times k$ transition matrix $A$ such that $A_{i,j}$ gives probability of transition from hidden state $Z = i$ to hidden state $Z = j$.
- initial probabilities $\pi_1 = P(Z_1 = 1), ..., \pi_k = P(Z_1 = k)$
- parameters of distributions of $X$ for each hidden state, e.g. if we assume Gaussian distribution then we have $(\mu_1, ... \mu_k), (\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_k)$

I wrote down that

$$P(x|\theta) = P(x_1 | \theta) \cdot P(x_2 | x_1; \theta) \cdot ... \cdot P(x_n | x_1, ..., x_{n-1}; \theta)$$
which is also how all video explanations and articles I've ever seen start. Then I realized when distribution is discrete, it doesn't make sense. All sources say at the beginning something like "we assume that matrix $A$, vector $\pi$ and probabilities $P(X = x | Z = k)$ are known", somehow going from knowing parameters of in many cases continuous distribution to discrete probabilities. How is it done?

Comment: For the discrete version, the distributions of $X$ (e.g. Gaussian distributions) are replaced with discrete probabilities. These discrete probabilities are the new parameters of the model. The formula you wrote still holds! If you have some model in mind, you will have to discretize your probability distributions. For example: if $x_1 = -1, x_2 = 1$, then if you have a Gaussian centered at 0 for $Z=1$ and a Gaussian centered at, say 1, with $\sigma=1$ for $Z=2$, then $P(X=x_1|Z=1)=1/2, P(X=x_2|Z=1)=1/2, P(X=x_1|Z=2)=1/(1+e^{-4}),P(X=x_2|Z=2)=e^{-4}/(1+e^{-4})$

Comment: @Daylight so by "probability od x1" they mean "value of probability density function at point x1", right? And another question is: what about parameter estimation, when we know only the data x1, ... xn and use Baum-Welch to fit the model, i.e. estimate its parameters. Do we estimate parameters of distribution then, or just probability densities again - it sounds bad because then we wouldnt be able to generate samples from fitted model.

Comment: 1. Yes. Although idk how they defined the PDF. I've only worked with discrete probabilities. With these, we just describe a PDF as some function $P$ such that $P(x_1)+P(x_2)+...+P(x_n) = 1$, where $\{x_i\}$ are the set of all observables. 2. You must give a guess for the probability densities initially for an HMM. You must define what the observables $x_1, ..., x_n$ are, though. Using these, and a sequence of observations $x(t=1), x(t=2), ...$, you can estimate the parameters $A$, $\Pi$, and $B$ (for the discrete case) or I guess $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (for the continuous case?)